# Highcharts displaying decimals on yearly xAxis

Tags: highcharts

My xAxis is displaying the years with decimals depending on the width of the screen, so if its small it will display(2012,2013,2014...) but when I increase the width of the screen it will display (2012, 2012.1, 2012.2, 2012.3 ...) and the decimal places change depending of the width(2012, 2012.5, 2013 ...)

I know that tickPixelInterval has some effect on that but I don't know what value to use, I`ve tried:

```
 xAxis: {
      tickPixelInterval: 100, //also tried 10 and 1 and 1000 even null
      crosshair: true
 }
```

What can I do so the chart only displays the whole number of the years (2012, 2013, 2014) not depending on the screen size and NOT giving an specific width to the div that renders the chart?

http://jsfiddle.net/antonioj1015/ff2m2bsx/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tickPixelInterval will give a setting of how far apart ticks should be - that won't help in your situation, and will in fact make sure the problem persists.

What you want is just `tickInterval`, and set it to 1, since your year numbers are in increments of 1:

- http://jsfiddle.net/ff2m2bsx/8/

if you won't always have increments of 1, another option is the `allowDecimals` property:

- http://jsfiddle.net/ff2m2bsx/9/

References:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickInterval
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.allowDecimals

A 3rd option is using a `datetime` x axis type, and setting the dates as your x axis values, and setting your tickInterval to one year.

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.type